# How to view RAM's SPD / timings table?

Tags: linux-mint, ram

In Linux Mint, how to get the same information presented in the lower half of the below picture?

Output by CPU-Z in Windows:

[image]

What I've tried:
Running CPU-Z 1.66 in Wine as Windows 95, 98 and XP.
CPU-G
i-nex
sudo lshw
sudo dmidecode
decode-dimms

Comment: With `sudo dmidecode -t memory` you can find manufacturer and part number and then it's not hard to find out CAS on the web

Answer (score 35):

`decode-dimms` is probably what you're looking for, but apparently you need to have the correct i2c module loaded before it works. Follow this tutorial:

http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_See_Live_RAM_Timings_Decode_DIMMS

I got it working after these steps:

```
sudo aptitude install i2c-tools
sudo modprobe eeprom
sudo modprobe i2c-i801
decode-dimms
```

Comment: `decode-dimms` is the closest I've found, it doesn't show different frequencies supported.

Comment: in my case eeprom was enough (no `sudo modprobe i2c-i801`), running `decode-dimms` initially outputs "No EEPROM found, try loading the eeprom or at24 module", so I've tried as advised.